# Google Apps Script Web App not working

Tags: web-applications, google-apps-script

I'm experimenting with Google Apps Scripts webapps. I've just got sidebars working and they're very useful but when I try to do a simple webapp, the code shows in the app instead of being executed:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

It must be something simple, but it's always simple when you know how.

Thanks for any help. ~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the template service in the HtmlService.

> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates

code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  var html= HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('Index');
      html.name = 'Bob';         
      return html.evaluate();
}
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <b>Hi <?=name?>!</b>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for this - it's helped me get a basic script working. Onwards from here. :-)